# Cconfiguring WSO2 proxy for JMS transformation to http request

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to configure JMS to HTTP transformation using WSO2. I tried doing soap/http to soap/http and it worked perfectly fine.

Are there any tips or did I miss any step?

When it is trying to convert JMS to http, I get to following error message.

```
2015-12-22 17:23:34,128 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-1] ERROR Axis2Sender Content-Length:0,Date:Tue, 22 Dec 2015 10:25:04 GMT,Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:432)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Share your proxy definition...

Comment: What is the version that are you using? Are you using with ActiveMq?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs mostly, when fails to register a call-back. Could you tryout following  properties.

```
<property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
<property action="set" name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
```